# auto_prepend_file PHP Core Directives not Loading

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have 4 web servers running Apache. These servers utilize two core php.ini directives to parse and insert content on every site.

**e.g.**

auto_prepend_file = /home/stats/scriptty.php

auto_append_file = /home/stats/scripttrry.php

**Docs**

auto_prepend_file
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

auto_append_file
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file

On Three of the servers, the directives are in working order. The server which is failing to include the 
files has PHP 5.4 and the others PHP 5.3.

When doing I grep the loaded config for PHP, the correct value is there and path to file, same with auto_append_file.

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep auto_prepend_file
```

I have compared other 3 server php configuration files to the failing server, they look similar. I've checked "**httpd.conf**" for "**AllowOverrideAll**" and / it's set to **All**.

I don't see any error on logs. I've tried loading it directly on htaccess instead, but it generates a system error.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/utilities.php"
```

Not sure where to go from here. Would you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: php from the command line usually uses a different php.ini file compared to php through a web server. consider using the phpinfo() function executed within the webserver env to see what ini file(s) it's using

Comment: Thanks. I've checked and the correct file ini is loaded. Still for some reason doesn't work. Could it be a bug in this version php 5.4.29? /usr/local/lib/php.ini @goat I noticed a couple entries for bugs regarding auto_prepend_file http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php